# Чтение после конца потока невозможно. C#

Tags: c#

Всем доброго времени суток, столкнулся с проблемой

> Чтения после конца потока невозможно

Дело в том что я читаю бинарный файл :

```
 while (reader2.PeekChar() > -1)
 {

    numb2 = reader2.ReadInt32();

    Int32 ndef2 = reader2.ReadInt32();

    BitVector32 bv2 = new BitVector32(ndef);

    int nr2 = bv2[nr_s];

    y2 = bv2[y_s];

    int sm2 = bv2[sm_s];

    ds2 = bv2[d_s];

    ms2 = bv2[m_s];

    int rs2 = bv2[r_s];

}
```

И так получилось что `numb2` имеет запись в файле поэтому `reader2.PeekChar() > -1` больше 1, но вот `ndef2` уже нету в файле, и я получаю ошибку чтения после конца потока, может есть более правильный метод инициализации данных в файле, и если дальше записи нет, то просто передать 0 и перейти дальше, либо пропускать и идти дальше, просто не хотелось бы делать что-то вроде:

```
 while (reader2.PeekChar() > -1)
 {

    numb2 = reader2.ReadInt32();

  if (reader2.PeekChar() > -1){

    Int32 ndef2 = reader2.ReadInt32();

    BitVector32 bv2 = new BitVector32(ndef);

    int nr2 = bv2[nr_s];

    y2 = bv2[y_s];

    int sm2 = bv2[sm_s];

    ds2 = bv2[d_s];

    ms2 = bv2[m_s];

    int rs2 = bv2[r_s];
    }

}
```

Или все же придется ставить еще одну проверку, как я написал выше ?
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Comment: Уже поздний вечер, возможно что я предлагаю глупость, но тем не менее -  Насколько я понял из Ваших слов, Вы установили, что файл имеет пропущенные данные. Вам известна длина блока данных читаемая за одну итерацию,   почему бы перед циклом не выяснить длину файла в байта, поделить ее на длину блока по модулю, и если будет остаток отличным от нуля, вместо выполнения последней итерации обработать ошибку так, как Вам надо.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Да я мог бы это сделать, например в буфер поместить количество байт а потом считать их через `Read`, но мой файл каждый раз дописывается и я не могу знать точной его длины, я могу знать только о том что есть значения `numb2` и все, а  `ndef2` может иметь информацию а может и не иметь её.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Возможно я не до конца вас понял, и не до конца понял ....

Comment: Правильно, ли я Вас понимаю, что Вы одновременно пишите и читаете из одного и того же файла?

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Да, одна программа пишет, вторая которую пишу я читает, и все это происходит одновременно.

Comment: Тогда у Вас проблемы совершенно другого сорта - синхронизация. Вам нужно "усыпить", читателя, до тех пор пока писатель, не завершит запись блока. Я плохой работник по ночам, если сами не справитесь, то вернусь к Вам утром.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов "Усыпить" - можно по времени например, но опять же, где гарантия того что я не попаду в тот момент когда будет происходить запись, а что если по условию например, в файл может попасть только одно значения `numb2` ? а вторую переменную мне нужно будет дописать самому ссылаясь на другой бинарный файл, тогда "усыпление" не поможет потому как  `numb2` будет иметь данные а вот `ndef2` уже нет, и не получит их пока я сам их туда не засуну, поэтому мне видимо нужно `ndef2` заполнить нулями, для этого видимо нужно делать проверку `if` иначе я пока не знаю как решить проблему

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае проблема заключалась в том, что запись и чтение были не в том же порядке. Чтение должно идти в том же порядке байтов, в котором записывались.